# How to copy the content of a data grid view in form1 to another data grid view in form2 in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, copy-paste

I have 2 win forms. In form 1 I have one `dataGridView` where I will collect all the data.
Now what I want to do is, when I press one button in form 1, I want to display form 2 and all the rows in the form1 data grid view needs to be copied to the data grid view in form 2.

How can I do this?

If this is not possible, is it possible to make data grid view in form1 as a floating control(which can move freely over the UI)?

I can copy from one `dataGridView` to another in the same form using the below code.

```
private DataGridView CopyDataGridView(DataGridView dgv_org)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataGridView2.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in dgv_org.Columns)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(dgvc.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
                }
            }
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            int k = 2;
            if (first == false)
            {
                k=0;
                first = true;
            }
                for (int i = k; i < dgv_org.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    row = (DataGridViewRow)dgv_org.Rows[i].Clone();
                    int intColIndex = 0;
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgv_org.Rows[i].Cells)
                    {
                        row.Cells[intColIndex].Value = cell.Value;
                        intColIndex++;
                    }
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                dataGridView2.Refresh();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Copy DataGridViw Error");
        }
        return dataGridView2;
    }
```

But cant copy to form2.

Comment: What kind of `DataSource` does your `DataGridView` on `form1` have?

Comment: Actually I have a connected hardware which will continuously send data. I am directly taking this data to the form1 DataGridView by the help of a background worker.

Comment: It's better for you to use some `DataSource` when dealing with `DataGridView`, adding rows and columns manually is OK but not very good.

Comment: Ok. But for now I have to follow this method. Is it possible to copy without using a DataSource?

Comment: Of course however it looks like that your method doesn't look well.

Comment: Can you please help me by showing how to do this? I am a new to c#

Comment: I'm not so sure about `.Clone` it probably isn't a deep clone and therefore more trouble than help, I would recommend a manual looping and adding row by row.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CopyAll(DataGridView from, DataGridView to)
{
    if (to.Columns.Count == 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in from.Columns)
        {
            to.Columns.Add(dgvc.Name, dgvc.HeaderText);
        }
    }

    to.Rows.Clear();

    foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvr in from.Rows)
    {
        List<string> cells = new List<string>();

        foreach(DataGridViewCell dgvc in dgvr.Cells)
        {
            cells.Add(dgvc.Value.ToString());
        }

        to.Rows.Add(cells.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't need this now, but hope it will help to someone else in the future.

```
 // Retrieve data from database in form1
 conn.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Image,Name from Input where ID = '" + txt_LID.Text + "'",conn);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 sda.Fill(dt);
 dGV_form1.DataSource = dt; 

 // Button Code on form1          
 Form2 lcp = new Form2();
 lcp.dGV_form2.DataSource = dt;
 lcp.Show();
 this.Hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 frm.dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
                if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
                        {
                            frm.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                            frm.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                            frm.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                            frm.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                            frm.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                            frm.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                            frm.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }   this 100% works i have used it
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to copy instead you can pass the reference.

First create datatable for a source

```
DataTable dt = new Datatable();
//Populate datatable
gridView.DataSource =dt;
```

On button click

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(dt);
f2.Show();
```

Form2 has overloaded constructor.